# Why is there no standardized way to avoid const method code duplication?

Tags: c++

To my experience it is a common phenomenon that the same code is used in a const and a non const version of a member method. One way to avoid code duplication of complex methods is to use a `const_cast` to remove the const-ness in the non const version like Scott Meyers recommended in Effective C++ (item 3). However this is not beneficial in very short methods that may just return a pointer - of course the duplication is not that problematic in this case. Still this makes me wonder whether there is a reason that there is no keyword or something equivalent to replace the casting.
I could imagine to use the following declaration:

```
autoconst Data* const getData() autoconst;
```

Of course this keyword would not add any functionality which was impossible to realize before but I think it would be nice to have. As far as I know the auto keyword similarly does not allow any new constructs but is a nice simplification in the code - admittedly much more extensive (please correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is whether this is in conflict with some rules in the C++ standard -   and if not, whether it is just not useful enough to get implemented.

Comment: Is there anyplace where this is a problem other than the accessor of a container where you need to change the return type?

Comment: Yes, when using iterators.  If a method accepts an iterator and doesn't change the members, there must be two methods, one for the const_iterator and another for {mutable} iterator.  Take incrementing as an example.

Comment: C++ is very...typing intensive. What would people do with their spare time if they could save implementing access functions/properties twice all day? ;)

Comment: @Thomas Matthews But `iterator`s are required to implicitly convert to `const_iterator`s for a given container.

Comment: My *opinion* is that it hasn't proven useful enough to address yet.  While it is duplication of code, standard library containers and [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) functions have prevented the need for me to actually write many of my own functions twice.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question slightly.  Whether there's a conflict has a definitive answer, but the "not useful enough" part of your question is a matter of opinion.

Comment: " ... whether it is just not useful enough to get implemented." This has been implemented in Java, so this isn't a pipe dream. Java doesn't have const obviously, but Java generics solve the basic idea (in a much more general way) of "let's improve the return type of a function, making use of whatever information is available at the call site about the dynamic type of the parameters"

Answer (score 5):

There is a standardized way, but not many people use it:

```
class X
{
    T data;
public:
    template<typename autoconst>
    friend /* or static */ auto get_data(autoconst& that) -> decltype(that.data)
    {
        // process that and return that.data
    }
};
```

It gets called as `get_data(x)` rather than `x.get_data()`, but one implementation serves both `const` and non-`const` usage, without casting or other un-typesafe techniques.

One can also have member functions to enable member call syntax.  That will require `const` and non-`const` variants, but no duplication of the "process `that.data`" step, because both can delegate to the friend template.

More complete example:

```
template<typename T>
class HyperMatrix
{
    int rows, cols, planes;
    T* data;
    /* they get initialized somehow */

public:
    template<typename ThisType>
    friend /* or static */ auto at(ThisType& that, int const r, int const c, int const p) -> decltype(*(that.data))
    {
        // argument validation logic not being duplicated
        if (r < 0 || r >= that.rows) throw index_exception();
        if (c < 0 || c >= that.cols) throw index_exception();
        if (p < 0 || p >= that.planes) throw index_exception();
        // complicated indexing expression, also not duplicated
        const index = (p * that.rows + r) * that.cols + c;
        return that.data[index];
    }

    // these enable a more natural syntax than at(hymatrix, 1, 2, 3)
    T& operator()(int const r, int const c, int const p)
    { return /* ThisType = HyperMatrix<T> */ at(this, r, c, p); }

    const T& operator()(int const r, int const c, int const p)
    { return /* ThisType = const HyperMatrix<T> */ at(this, r, c, p); }
};
```

Example with no trivial workaround:

```
template<typename T>
class BalancedJumpTable
{
public:
    template<typename ThisType, typename Functor>
    friend /* or static */ auto for_each(ThisType& that, Functor f)
    {
        // complicated code for walking the tree not duplicated
        // deep inside loops and recursive calls, we find
           f(that->something());
        // maybe there's even some filtering logic which causes only
        // only certain items to be passed to the callback
    }

    template<typename Functor>
    void for_each(Functor f)
    { return for_each(this, f); }

    void for_each(Functor f) const
    { return for_each(this, f); }
};
```

Comment: Interesting and clean solution - but still it's a little bit annoying that this cannot be realized with a member method. To the second suggestion: I think you can also achieve this by using two member methods and a private const processing function.

Comment: @w1th0utnam3 I think you mean "private friend processing function".  And with C++17 return type deduction, you can often drop the `->decltype`

Comment: @w1th0utnam3: No, you can't use a private const helper for the same reason you can't delegate to the public const version... A const member function can't return a non-const reference to a data member.

Comment: My vote would be on a getData() = default(m_data) shortcut in the same style as all those noisy constructor versions are now handled. ;) Or simply property(m_data) and save even more typing.

Comment: @BenVoigt But if the processing method did anything you were not allowed to do in a const method it wouldn't make any sense trying to summarize it in one method in the first place.

Comment: @w1th0utnam3: It's the caller that will be doing different things.  The classic example is `operator[]` on any container.  If the container is const, the return needs to be a `const` reference.  If the container is non-const, the return needs to be a non-const reference.  But you already knew that, based on your comments to Blindy.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was talking about your second suggestion: why do you need a friend template if you require a const and non-const delegating member method anyway (when you try to implement this using member methods)? The friend may be replaced with a private method in this case.

Comment: @w1th0utnam3: It can be a private static member function template instead of a friend.  But it cannot be a non-static const member, which is what your first comment suggested.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, then I think I didn't get what you want to do inside of the get_data method or what you mean with 'One can also have member functions to enable member call syntax.' Could you please explain this again?

Comment: @BenVoigt But except for the return which is different regarding the const-ness, everything inside of the template may also be implemented in a private method. For example `int index(r,c,b) const` which does the bounds checking and returns the index. Now the operators can be written as `return data.at[index(r,c,b)];`. This provides nearly no advantage does it? I can't think of an example where the template helps if you want have access via member methods. EDIT: It only reduces it to one line instead of at most two lines in more complex cases.

Comment: @w1th0utnam3: Ok, now consider a `for_each` function for a complex data structure.  The callback can take `element&` only if the data structure is non-const.  However if the container is const, the callback must take `const element&`.  Walking the data structure is a very complex procedure and cannot be encapsulated in a single return value from a `const` helper function.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, you're right. If the retrieval of the pointer to the data is somehow "dynamic" it cannot be implemented using a const member method if you want to output a non const pointer. EDIT: And of course I only delegated the problem to the [] operator in my example above.

Comment: But this also demonstrates that there are cases where the code could get more elegant with a new keyword or some other logic like generics or whatever ;)

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sold on your need. In fact I'm not sold that your code is entirely correct to begin with if you find yourself repeatedly casting away `const`.

Consider that you can pass non-`const` objects to functions expecting `const` objects. `const` on a parameter is simply a contract that the callee won't change the object -- it either does or it does not. If it does change it, passing a `const` object is a mistake (whose mistake is debateable, but there is a mistake somewhere). If it doesn't change it, you can pass anything.

I'm not sure what else to say besides try rewriting your code with correct contracts, or if you can't be bothered, simply don't use any `const` at all.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem correctly. I'm talking about a member method that returns a pointer (for example in containers) and is overloaded with a const version and a non const version. Often they both do exactly the same and the code may be complex. So this leads to code duplication if you don't implement the non-const version by casting away the constness of the const version.

Comment: The same applies to reference return values. If you want to allow both changing the content of the returned reference in one context as well as allowing const -only usage in another context where the "container" is const, you need to supply both.

Comment: I understood your problem just fine, I just don't think your solution is correct. If both versions do the same, why do you have two? The function obviously works with `const` objects, as in *it promises not to change the object*. Why do you insist on a non-`const` version as well?

Comment: @user2225104 this isn't Shroedinger's cat, this is C++. You as a function writer know if you'll change the object or not. You don't just sort of half-guess then give up and implement both for the sake of it.

Comment: @Blindy Well, there may be other classes which should only be allowed to read data from the container so they require a const version because they only got a const pointer to the container but other classes may have to edit the data. Do you think this is bad design?

Comment: You as the implementer of an object do not have influence over how your object is used. We talk about return values here. The function calling the accessor might have a const reference or a non-const reference to the object. ``class Point { public: int &getX(); const int & getX() const;  };`` is what we discuss. ``void foo( const Point& point ) ... `` vs. ``void bar( Point& point )... ``

Comment: @w1th0utnam3, I think what you're missing by hand-waving is that these cases you're talking about aren't the same function, as it's advertised in the OP. You have `vector<T>::get(int idx)`, that returns a non-`const` object. Where's the "other version"? Another function with another name? Why would you even return a `const` object from a mutable collection?

Comment: Because maybe there are functions which write the vector and others by design are supposed to /use/ the vector but not modify it. It is all about the user of the accessor. Maybe a function receives a const Point& (in my example) as input and has a Point&result argument where it stores the result.

Comment: I'll say again that you can pass non-`cost` arguments to ones expecting `const`. And that's because, again repeating myself, `const` in a function definition is the contract the callee promises to uphold, it has nothing to do with what the caller wants (it's only validation on the caller side, ie can the argument be cast to what the function is expecting).

Comment: ``void GetMiddle( const Point& p1, const Point& p2, Point& result ) { rsult.getX() = (p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2; }`` Do that without having both a const and a non-const version of Point::getX()...

Comment: @Blindy: You're completely ignoring the _return value_, which is sometimes `const` and sometimes not `const`.  For an example, view `vector::operator[]` and `vector::at` and `vector::back` and `vector::front` and `vector::begin` and `vector::end` and `vector::data`., which all have the same issue that the OP is discussing.

Comment: This is an example of a broader issue, where sometimes the return type could usefully be 'annotated' with extra information as a function of the dynamic types of the parameters. E.g. if you pass two `Circle*` pointers to `Shape* getBiggestShape(Shape*,Shape*)`, then it would be nice if you could implicitly static_cast the result to `Circle*`. It's "obvious" that this is safe, so the compiler should understand this. You might think that templates are a complete solution to this, but you can't take the address of a function template. This extension to the language would allow such pointers

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Interesting point. Are there some elaborate concepts of this feature to see how this could benefit different applications?

Comment: @w1th0utnam3 (I have very little experience using Java to solve real problems, and I'm definitely not a fan of Java, but I find this feature to be very compelling). Another example of what could be done with "C++ Generics" is that a `std::list<Circle*>` could be implicitly and safely casted to a reference to `const std::list<Shape*>` (it's `const` so that you couldn't then sneak a `Square*` into the `list`)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You have my signature to promote this for implementation in C++20.